# Sequelize - Pagination works not correct in findAndCountAll when relations count functions added

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am trying to implement pagination with findAndCountAll method, but after i adding count functions for relations tables it gave me a result with many duplicated rows, for example i have Authors table with two authors, and m2m relation with AuthorFollowers table with only two rows, so it should give me only two Authors rows with `count: 2`, and `followersCount: 2`, but it give me 9 Authors rows. if i'm using `distinct: true` it shows correct rows and `count: 2`, but in fact when i use limit and offset fields it acts like there are 9 rows, so if i set `limit: 1` there should be only 2 pages, but there are 9 pages instead. if i'm not using `distinct: true` the result of my query will be not correct: `{ count: 9, rows:...}`.

My method:

```
async findAll(paginate: PaginateDto) {
    const followerIdCol = '"author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"'
    const authorTokensCol = '"author_tokens"."id"'
    return await this.authorRepository.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['collections', 'updatedAt', 'userId'],
            include: [
                [
                    literal(`COUNT(${authorTokensCol}) OVER (PARTITION BY "Author"."id", ${followerIdCol})`),
                    'tokensCount',
                ],
                [
                    literal(`COUNT(${followerIdCol}) OVER (PARTITION BY "Author"."id", ${authorTokensCol})`),
                    'followersCount',
                ],
            ],
        },
        include: [
            { model: Token, as: 'author_tokens', attributes: [], duplicating: false },
            {
                model: User,
                as: 'author_followers',
                attributes: [],
                through: { attributes: [] },
                duplicating: false,
            },
        ],
        offset: !paginate || !paginate.limit || !paginate.page ? null : 0 + (+paginate.page - 1) * +paginate.limit,
        limit: !paginate || !paginate.limit ? null : paginate.limit,
        order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']],
        distinct: true,
    })
}
```

This method gives a correct result if i'm not applying limit and offset:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5",
      "createdAt": "2022-08-03T19:41:41.856Z",
      "tokensCount": "4",
      "followersCount": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "eeb84240-9cd7-4268-97c0-b6c92fd5a45e",
      "createdAt": "2022-08-03T19:45:09.015Z",
      "tokensCount": "0",
      "followersCount": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

and if i trying to set limit  and offset it works like there is 9 rows instead of 2, because in fact my method generates wrong query which gives 9 rows result instead of 2 rows:

```
SELECT 
  "Author"."id", 
  "Author"."createdAt", 
  COUNT("author_tokens"."id") OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Author"."id", "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"
  ) AS "tokensCount", 
  COUNT(
    "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"
  ) OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Author"."id", "author_tokens"."id"
  ) AS "followersCount" 
FROM 
  "authors" AS "Author" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "tokens" AS "author_tokens" ON "Author"."id" = "author_tokens"."authorId" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    "authors_folowers" AS "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers" 
    INNER JOIN "users" AS "author_followers" ON "author_followers"."id" = "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"
  ) ON "Author"."id" = "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followingId" 
ORDER BY 
  "Author"."createdAt" ASC;

"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"eeb84240-9cd7-4268-97c0-b6c92fd5a45e"  "2022-08-03 12:45:09.015-07"    0   1
```

But this query with DISTINCT keyword after SELECT works correctly, even when i adding limit and offset values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  "Author"."id", 
  "Author"."createdAt", 
  COUNT("author_tokens"."id") OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Author"."id", "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"
  ) AS "tokensCount", 
  COUNT(
    "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"
  ) OVER (
    PARTITION BY "Author"."id", "author_tokens"."id"
  ) AS "followersCount" 
FROM 
  "authors" AS "Author" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "tokens" AS "author_tokens" ON "Author"."id" = "author_tokens"."authorId" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    "authors_folowers" AS "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers" 
    INNER JOIN "users" AS "author_followers" ON "author_followers"."id" = "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followerId"
  ) ON "Author"."id" = "author_followers->AuthorsFollowers"."followingId" 
ORDER BY 
  "Author"."createdAt" ASC;

"67585770-4728-44c7-8a02-ce9efc5273a5"  "2022-08-03 12:41:41.856-07"    4   2
"eeb84240-9cd7-4268-97c0-b6c92fd5a45e"  "2022-08-03 12:45:09.015-07"    0   1
```

How can i fix my sequelize method to add DISTINCT keyword after SELECT? Or mayn=be therer is another way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on my own question. after many tries i found a solution to avoid N+1 problem. this solution is to use literals with direct raw queries instead of queries with includes:

```
async findAll2(paginate?: FilndAllAuthorsFiltersDto) {
    return await this.authorRepository.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: [
            'id',
            'userId',
            'createdAt',
            [literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) from tokens where "authorId"="Author"."id")'), 'tokensCount'],
            [
                literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) from authors_folowers where "followingId"="Author"."id")'),
                'followersCount',
            ],
        ],
        offset: !paginate || !paginate.limit || !paginate.page ? null : 0 + (+paginate.page - 1) * +paginate.limit,
        limit: !paginate || !paginate.limit ? null : paginate.limit,
        order: [
            [
                paginate.sortBy === 'byFollowersCount' ? literal('"followersCount"') : 'createdAt',
                paginate.sortDirection,
            ],
        ],
    });
}
```